# How to press a button from another form using C#?

Tags: c#, forms, button

I have 2 forms:

1. Form1 that make a screenshot.
2. Form2 that have 2 buttons to manipulate the screenshot created by form1.

Form1 also have a "hidden" button that contain the method to save the screenshot.

My questions:

How can i click the form1's button from form2?
and
How can i check when the form1 is closed and then close form2 too?

I've tried something like this but nothing happens when i click form2 save button:

```
var form = Form.ActiveForm as Form1;
if (form != null)
{
    form.button1.PerformClick();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all the normal way multiple forms work is that when you close down the Startup form then the secondary forms will close also. If you are creating your `Form2` in `Form1` I would show it by using `(your second Forms Instance).Show(this)`. You could then access the Form by Form2's Parent Property.  i.e.

```
      var form = (Form1)this.Owner();
```

You should then be able to access all of the public methods of `Form1`, Also I would take the code that you are using to save your screenshot and put into a public method, no need to have it in a Button's click event especially if the button is hidden.

Here is a quick example:

**Form1**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm = new Form2();
        frm.Show(this);
    }

}
```

**Form2**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var frm = (Form1)this.Owner;
        if (frm != null)
            frm.button1.PerformClick();
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to use that hidden button. I will try your method and i'll be back.

Comment: ->Object reference not set to an instance of an object. var form = (Form1)this.Parent;
            form.button1.PerformClick();

Comment: How are you creating form2. You need to assign the parent at that time.

Comment: My bad, use `Var frm = (Form1)this.Owner;` instead. I will post an updated code example

Comment: Worked. Thank you @Mark Hall

Comment: The "button1_Click" function in "Form1" needs to be public.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making a hidden button just make a method not linked to a button.

In `Form1.cs`:

```
public void SaveScreenshot()
{
    //TODO: Save the Screenshot
}
```

In `Form2.cs`:

```
Form1 form = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().FirstOrDefault();
if (form != null) {
    form.SaveScreenshot();
}
```

Also make sure to declare the `SaveScreenshot` method as `public` or `internal`.

I changed the code that gets `Form1`. If you click a button on `Form2` then `Form2` will be the `ActiveForm`, so your code will never "see" `Form1`. I used LINQ methods in my code that will only work if you have a `using System.Linq;` at the top of your code.